# How to implement flatten(ffa: F<F<A>>) -> F<A> in Rust?

Tags: rust, functional-programming

### question and my goal

My goal is to let [this (playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=12772c44c5a42f365d927fe0a01202c6) compile. Below is the core of the code. This is attempt to implement `FlatMap` for all `F<F<A>>`, such as `Option<Option<i32>>`.

```rust
trait HKT1 {
    type Unwrapped;
    type Wrapped<T>;
}

trait FlatMap: HKT1 + Sized {
    fn flat_map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Self::Wrapped<B>
    where
        F: FnOnce(Self::Unwrapped) -> Self::Wrapped<B>;

    // Below cannot compile
    fn flatten<A>(ffa: Self::Wrapped<Self::Wrapped<A>>) -> Self::Wrapped<A>
    // How to set generic bound correctly?
    where
        Self::Wrapped<Self::Wrapped<A>>: FlatMap
    {
        ffa.flat_map(|x| x)
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:26
   |
15 |         ffa.flat_map(|x| x)
   |                          ^ expected HKT1::Wrapped, found HKT1::Unwrapped
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<<Self as HKT1>::Wrapped<<Self as HKT1>::Wrapped<A>> as HKT1>::Wrapped<_>`
              found associated type `<<Self as HKT1>::Wrapped<<Self as HKT1>::Wrapped<A>> as HKT1>::Unwrapped`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
6  | trait FlatMap: HKT1 + Sized {
   | --------------------------- this type parameter
...
11 |     fn flatten<A>(ffa: Self::Wrapped<Self::Wrapped<A>>) -> Self::Wrapped<A>
   |                                                            ---------------- expected `<Self as HKT1>::Wrapped<A>` because of return type
...
15 |         ffa.flat_map(|x| x)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `Self`, found associated type
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<Self as HKT1>::Wrapped<A>`
              found associated type `<<Self as HKT1>::Wrapped<<Self as HKT1>::Wrapped<A>> as HKT1>::Wrapped<_>`
   = note: you might be missing a type parameter or trait bound
```

`HKT1` is a way to emulate `F<_>` and allow all traits that are based on it to access `F` and `_` separately. I learned from [this blog](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/monads-gats-nightly-rust/).

### what I am trying to do

I'm trying to build up a functional programming crate which is kind of translating Scala lib cats to Rust. (Current work [here](https://github.com/duskmoon314/cats)). To implement the higher kinded type, I follow [this blog](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/monads-gats-nightly-rust/) and define the `HKT1` trait. It is quite elegant until I want to implement `flatten(ffa: F<F<A>>) -> F<A>` but cannot figure out how to set the generic bound correctly.

It seems easy to implement if I leave it blank in the trait. For example:

```rust
trait FlatMap: HKT1 + Sized {
    fn flat_map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Self::Wrapped<B>
    where
        F: FnOnce(Self::Unwrapped) -> Self::Wrapped<B>;
        
    fn flatten<A>(ffa: Self::Wrapped<Self::Wrapped<A>>) -> Self::Wrapped<A>;
}

struct MyF<T>(pub T);

impl<A> HKT1 for MyF<A> {
    type Unwrapped = A;
    type Wrapped<T> = MyF<T>;
}

impl<T> FlatMap for MyF<T> {
    fn flat_map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> MyF<B>
    where
        F: FnOnce(Self::Unwrapped) -> MyF<B>,
    {
        f(self.0)
    }
    
    fn flatten<A>(ffa: MyF<MyF<A>>) -> MyF<A> {
        ffa.flat_map(|x| x)
    }
}
```

But I would like to have a default implementation through `flat_map`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is not possible to implement flatten for an arbitrary F.

Comment: @n.m. In my understanding, `flatten` can be implemented through `flat_map(self: F<F<A>>, f: F<A> -> F<A>)`. It takes the inner `F<A>` and returns. Are there problems here? In addition, I think it is unnecessary to discuss other bound like `Functor` so I haven't mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Oh sorry. If you have flat_map then flatten is just flat_map applied to the identity function. You seem to bedoimg this already so the problem seems to be with HKT1. Why is it needed?

Comment: @n.m. HKT1 is a way to emulate `F[_]` and all traits (Functor, SemigroupK, .etc) are based on it to access the inner type. (I learned this from the blog which I mention in the question) More specifically, `Option<T>` can be impl via `HKT1<Unwrapped = T, Wrapped = Option<T>>` and `Functor: HKT1 {fmap<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Self::Wrapped<B> where F: FnMut(Self::Unwrapped) -> B}`

Comment: Your `flat_map` callback fn is expecting `FnOnce(Self::Unwrapped) -> Self::Wrapped<B>`. The parameter is `Self::Unwrapped` but the return is expecting `Self::Wrapped<B>`, so just returning the parameter its not going to be the right type (`ffa.flat_map(|x| x)`).

Comment: I think you need `for<T>` to implement that.

Comment: @pigeonhands I expect the parameter to be `Wrapped<Wrapped<_>>`'s `Unwrapped` (`Wrapped<_>`). But I haven't found out how to achieve this.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I know little about `for<T>`. Do you mean `Higher-ranked trait bounds`? It seems to have something to do with lifetimes.

Comment: Yes, but not with lifetimes. What currently supported is lifetimes, `for<'a>`. But I think you need full higher-ranked trait bounds, `for<T>` with types, to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

## A solution via `EqT`

I just learned how to achieve this from [the implementation of crate functional](https://docs.rs/functional/0.0.5/functional/trait.Equals.html). (Well, the implementation is a little different from above)

The key idea is to add a trait `EqT`, whose purpose is to assert two types are equal. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dd1eeedc88be6a7c67138ca15b63835b))

```rust
trait HKT1 {
    type Unwrapped;
    type Wrapped<T>;
}

trait FlatMap: HKT1 + Sized {
    fn flat_map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Self::Wrapped<B>
    where
        F: FnOnce(Self::Unwrapped) -> Self::Wrapped<B>;
        
    fn flatten<A>(self) -> Self::Wrapped<A>
    where
        Self::Unwrapped: EqT<Self::Wrapped<A>>,
    {
        self.flat_map(|x| x.cast())
    }
}

trait EqT<T> {
    fn cast(self) -> T;
}
impl<T> EqT<T> for T {
    fn cast(self) -> T {
        self
    }
}
```

Then we can easily implement and use `flatten`:

```rust
struct MyF<T>(pub T);

impl<A> HKT1 for MyF<A> {
    type Unwrapped = A;
    type Wrapped<T> = MyF<T>;
}

impl<T> FlatMap for MyF<T> {
    fn flat_map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> MyF<B>
    where
        F: FnOnce(Self::Unwrapped) -> MyF<B>,
    {
        f(self.0)
    }
}

let ffa = MyF(MyF(1));
let fa = ffa.flatten();
println!("{:?}", fa); // Expect MyF(1)
```